# How to I add a MIME type for a single specific file without extension in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, mime-types

I've been getting a lot of 404 notifications on the *.well-known/traffic-advice* location on my server. After doing some research it turns out the Chrome Privacy Preserving Prefetch Proxy tries to find instructions on prefetching content from the website.

I would like to add this file to give a proper response, but the file needs a specific MIME type: application/trafficadvice+json

In IIS it is easy to add a new MIME type for a specific extension, but in this case the 'traffic-advise' file has no extension. Also it's not advisable to specify a MIME type for all extension-less files.

How can I add the MIME type for this specific file in IIS (or web.config)?

Comment: As far as I know, iis does not support the media type `application/trafficadvice+json`.

Comment: @VDWWD Did you even read the question?

Comment: Yes I did, that is why I deleted the comments. But why not just give it an extension?

Comment: Simply use `.`, which means files without extensions.

Comment: @LexLi Because I obviously don't want all files without extension to be of type application/trafficadvice+json

Comment: @VDWWD Because that is the specific location and file the google 'bot' is crawling

Comment: Combine that with location tags and you can minimize the impact.

Comment: You can set a content type in the response if the file is generated by an endpoint Like an API or ActionResult returning a file.

Comment: @LexLi Doesn't seem possible because of the dot in the path. Exception = <location> path attribute must be a relative virtual path.  It cannot start with any of ' ' '.' '/' or '\'.

Comment: @VDWWD Might work but not sure if I want to follow that path. Must be a simpler solution.

Comment: Another possible solution, based on WDWWD and LexLI 's comments is to rename the file to traffic-advice.xxx, thus having an extension. Adding that extension to the MIME types and making a redirect from traffic-advice to traffic-advice.xxx. Still not the most elegant solution but should work I guess.

Comment: If you never use location tags before, you should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other solutions did not work for me, I used the following workaround to make it work:

1. Add an extension to the file (/.well-known/traffic-advice) so it becomes traffic-advice.tdjson
2. Add the MIME type for tdjson in web.config (or use IIS):

```
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".tdjson" mimeType="application/trafficadvice+json" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
```

3. Install the URl rewrite module (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)
4. Add this rule to your Redirects.config file

```
    <rule name="wellknown trafficadvice" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^\.well-known\/traffic-advice$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/.well-known/traffic-advice.tdjson" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

5. Done

Answer (score 1):

You might get started from

```xml
    <location path=".well-known/traffic-advice">
        <system.webServer>
            <staticContent>
                <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="application/trafficadvice+json" />
            </staticContent>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```

Revise it if you have multiple files with different MIME types in mind.

Comment: Yes I did this per your suggestion in the comments of the main thread and I replied that this is not working due to the starting dot in the path.  So I'm not sure why you are posting this as an answer now?

Comment: @Onthrax this is the answer because IIS configuration allows the path to start with a dot. If you experienced a 500 error from ASP.NET 4.x, that’s a different story where you can convert `.well-known` to an IIS application and put it under an application pool without ASP.NET runtime.

Comment: Couldn't get it working even after converting to application and such. Thanks for the help though